# mysqli_real_connect() often takes around 5 seconds,even on developing environment

Tags: php, mysql, windows, database-connection

```
mysqli_real_connect($connection, $url['host'], $url['user'], $url['pass'], substr($url['path'], 1), $url['port'], NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS);
```

What's the reason that it can take much time to make a connection?

Now about **3** out of **8** connections will hang for **5** seconds or even more.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are connecting to the MySQL server using a domain name, and the DNS resolution takes too much time.

There is a similar question that was addressed by using IP for the conection, but the waiting time in that case was in the order of milliseconds, take a look at it at:
[Retrieve how long it takes to establish a connection with PHP mysqli_real_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938188/retrieve-how-long-it-takes-to-establish-a-connection-with-php-mysqli-real-connec)

Answer (score 0):

I think your mysql server is overloaded. you can try raising your 'max_connections' in my.cnf . also check your logs for any helpfull information.

Comment: what about the behaviour of mysql_connect() ?

Comment: That doesn't make sense, there are only 2 connections on the developing mysql server.