# Retrieve how long it takes to establish a connection with PHP mysqli_real_connect()

Tags: php, mysql, performance, mysqli

I am trying to find the bottleneck for an internal PHP application. I can only get around 10 req/sec before requests start taking 5 or more seconds to complete. The CPU load on the server is nothing, `vmstat` does not show any I/O wait or swap. I have a strong suspicion it is the connection to an external MySQL server causing the slow down. I am using:

```
mysqli_real_connect(...)
```

Is there a way to time how long it takes to connect, and log it somewhere, so I can view how long the actual handshake and connection to the MySQL server is taking.

Comment: use microtime() to know how long it takes to establish connection.http://php.net/manual/fr/function.microtime.php

Comment: Is your connection to url/server `localhost`? If so, change it to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: The connection is over a private network to an external server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$start_time = microtime(TRUE);

// do anything ... mysqli

$stop_time = microtime(TRUE);

$duration = $stop_time - $start_time;

var_dump($duration);
```

Comment: Does putting the timer code around `mysqli_real_connect()` really tell me when PHP makes a MySQL connection, or does the actual connection not happen until I call `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: Why should a connection to the database server happen, even before you ever plan to use it? ... So yes, (imho, even if I am "`the master imself`"), mysql(i)/PDO gets executed when called - so, between the incredible suggested start and stop sequences.

Comment: So I am seeing times of `130.1ms` simply around the `mysqli_real_connect()` call when idle. That seems extremely high. The MySQL server has no load and seems tip top. When I refresh over and over again, the call time drops to around `20-30ms` consistently.

Comment: Please, don't ask me. I would say that 0.13 seconds is too much, but I don't know your configuration. I (don't know why, just "upgaded" to PDO, currently) cannot use persistent connections (what I would prefer) have connection times within the 0.00xSeconds [at least on reconnect after server start].

Comment: I put the MySQL server address into `/etc/hosts` and connection time dropped to `1ms`. Wow, the lots of latency in DNS.

Comment: So, your `localhost` versus `127.0.0.1` did do the job? ... I am like a prophet, telling this all day via Stackoverflow ... but, too many "know-it-all" guys here ... anyway, I have to "eat Pizza" ... NO ... I have to go "to Ibiza" ;)

Comment: No, the MySQL server is not localhost/127.0.0.1 it resides on a different physical machine.

Comment: So what I should tell you/TheWorld(?): Preferable use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` ... even if this is not the answer to YOUR question.